# Adding Multiple Name Lists to Conditional Dropdown in Excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

I'm creating a spreadsheet that has dropdowns that have content based on more than one cell, and add different things according to those conditions.  I've been searching for the past hour trying to find something online (here, Google, etc), and either I haven't been searching for the right thing, or no one's thought to try it before, but either way, here we go:

The point is that, in Data Validation, the references for named groups seem to be only singular, but I want to be able to add multiple named groups to a single drop-down list depending on what's available.  For instance, one drop down box (D1) can have values based on two cells (A1, A2), and both are dropdowns themselves.  If A1 and A2 both say that something should show in D1's list, I want both to show up (in an order specified by the order in which I check the cells).  Is this even possible with Excel, and if so, how the heck do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow man this was really a challenge I enjoyed this one quite a bit! Sorry the first answer was not what you needed but this should do!

So first I set up my sheet as follows:

[image]

I then added the True and False conditions for Choice 1 & 2 using data validation
[image]

I then input formulas in Column H to create a new list based on the choices

```
=IF($A$2=TRUE,E2,"")  
=IF($A$2=TRUE,E3,"")  
=IF($A$2=TRUE,E4,"")  
=IF($A$2=TRUE,E5,"")  
=IF($A$2=TRUE,E6,"")  
=IF($B$2=TRUE,F2,"")  
=IF($B$2=TRUE,F3,"")  
=IF($B$2=TRUE,F4,"")  
=IF($B$2=TRUE,F5,"")  
=IF($B$2=TRUE,F6,"")
```

So for the first 5 formulas if the choice is A2 is True then it will display the appropriate item from List 1 into the Dynamic List.

For the last 5 formulas if the choice is B2 is True then it will display the appropriate item from List 2 into the Dynamic List

For Example:

If A2 = True & B2 = False
[image]

If A2 = False & B2 = True
[image]

At this point I realized that the spaces in the dynamic list would be a problem so I had to create an ARRAY to remove the spaces. There are tons of examples online to do this but this was the simplest formula. (I can't explain ARRAY formulas I use them every once in awhile but don't fully understand them I am sorry about that)

In I2 I placed the following ARRAY formula (The cell above I2 must remain blank)

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$11, MATCH(0, IF(ISBLANK($H$2:$H$11), 1, COUNTIF(I1:$I$1, $H$2:$H$11)), 0))
```

You then must press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER after inputting the formula to make it an array formula

Then drag the formula down to I11 using autofill

[image]

Then in C2 I created a dynamic drop down using data validation and an OFFSET Formula to refer to the valid text items contained in the indexed list (The OFFSET formula is is explained here http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm)

The formula is:

```
=OFFSET($I$2,0,0,MATCH("*",$I$2:$I$11,-1),1)
```

The OFFSET Formula is used in the source field of the Data Validation for C2
[image]

Now your list in C2 is dynamic based on the Choices in A2 and B2

For example:

A2 and B2 = False
[image]

A2 = True and B2 = False
[image]

A2 = True and B2 = True
[image]

A2 = False and B2 = True
[image]

There might be another way to do this with VBA (I am not that great with it) as well but for now this should do! Hope this solves your issue!

Comment: I have to admit, that is rather detailed and does what I said I wanted in the first place.  This definitely deserves an answer.  I may have decided to go the VBA route anyway, since I had to enable macros to be able to clear a list cell based on another list cell (which probably could also be solved in a way similar to this, now that I think about it), but I'm definitely going to remember this answer in case I ever need a non-VBA solution again in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible I was able to do this:

1. I made list of items in column D and E in this instance:

   Column D contains the letters A,B,C,D
   Column E contains E,G,H,I

   The values can be what ever you need it to be.
2. I then made a drop down list in cell B1 using Data Validation -> List referencing the list in column D
   [image]
3. I then made a drop down list in cell C1 using Data Validation -> List referencing the list in column E
   [image]
4. I Then made a drop down list in cell A1 using Data Validation -> List referencing the drop down lists that are in B1 and C1
   [image]

This dynamically changes drop down list in A1 based on the selected values in B1 and C1

In the image below I selected B and H which changed the list in cell A1 to have the options B and H.

[image]

Comment: Would really appreciate more specifics in the answer.  You really only did half an answer with saying it could be done and not saying how.  You can use other things like Gyazo (screenshot and image upload utility) or any cloud storage system to store the images for a detailed, step-by-step walkthrough.

Comment: I have added images to better illustrate my answer. The the text did not change much. Please note I did not have enough rep before to post images when I posted my answer.

Comment: Ah, now I see where you were going with it.  That's an interesting trick, but not quite what I was going for.  To adapt that to my problem would be rather tedious.  In terms of your example, what I want is to be able to have the entire contents of ranges D and E to be available in list A based on whether B and C, respectively, are certain values.  It looks like the only way to accomplish this with any amount of sanity is with VBA.

Comment: Explain a little more it sounds like another problem I have solved for another I just haven't posted it to their question yet hopefully it could work for yours.

Comment: OK, say lists B and C each have only two values possible, T and F.  If B1 is "T", I want named range D to be added to list A's available choices.  Same for C1 and range E.  But, if both are "T", both named ranges need to be added to A's available choices, at the same time.  Take that and scope it up to have a range lookup based on B's and C's values that are then added to A's available choices.

Comment: Ah a little more complicated sounds like a nice little challenge I think it can still be done. So will the list size for range D and E be the same (i.e. 10 items) or will they somstimes change?

Comment: D and E will always be fixed ranges.

Comment: I should be able to do it I have to work for the next 12 hrs but I will try to work on it in my spare time

Comment: It was a lot harder than I thought but I was able to get it I posted it in a new  answer